# Ruby won't let me import the BigDecimal library

Tags: ruby, cygwin

I tried using `require 'bigdecimal'`, but I got an error saying that it can't load the file.

```
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- bigdecimal (LoadError)
from /usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
```

What's going on here?

Comment: `require 'bigdecimal'` works for me on **2.5.0**

Comment: I'm using Ruby 2.3.6.

Comment: Is there any other relevant context that may be missing? `bigdecimal` has been around even prior to 2.0, so it is doubtful to be a version problem. Do you have a snippet from the code where it is required?

Comment: I'm guessing the library simply isn't installed.  I'm using the Cygwin version at the moment.

Comment: Seems it would have caused a compiler error in that case, but TBH I never compiled Ruby under Cygwin, so not going to guess.

Comment: To reduce things to the minimum, try require 'bigdecimal' from irb or pry.

Answer (score 0):

ruby-bigdecimal is a separate package in Cygwin. You'll need to install that.