# 'rails server' causes loadError 'cannot load such file -- bigdecimal.so' locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle, fedora, gemfile

I am running ruby version 2.6.5, rails version 5.1.7, on a Fedora 31 VM. I'm trying to run a rails web app from someone else to continue their work on my machine. I have all of the correct gems installed but keep running into the LoadError for 'bigdecimal.so' when I try to launch the server.

I have tried:

1) `gem install bigdecimal`

2) putting `gem 'bigdecimal'` in my Gemfile and running `bundle update`

3) when I test `require bigdecimal` in the irb shell, 'true' is the output

None of these have worked. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does this help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51682003/ruby-wont-let-me-import-the-bigdecimal-library

Comment: Thanks but I;m not using cywgin